# Extracting values from XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I the following format:

```
<Results>
   <Value type="range"> 45-50 </Value>
   <Value type="range"> 65-58 </Value>
   <Value type="range"> 76-80 </Value>
   <Value type="range"> 48-60 </Value>
</Results>
```

I want to extract get the type value which is range and also the number.

this is my java code snippet,

```
NodeList mNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("Value");
String elementAttr = nElement.getAttribute("type"); // here i get the attribute to be "range"
```

but i am not sure how to extract the actual range "45-50".

Comment: did you intend to leave the ending '"' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
nElement.getTextContent().trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use

```
public static String attributeText(Node node, String namedItem) {
        String retValue = null;
        Node attribute = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem(namedItem);
        if (attribute != null) {
            retValue = attribute.getNodeValue();
        }
        return retValue;
    }
```